# Trying to make countDownTimer inside doInBackGroung

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im trying to make a CountDownTimer inside a doInbackGround but its returning this error for me. Why cant I put this inside the doInBackGround. Im doing this to the tread last longer to execute.

Im having to call 2 times this Asynctask. When I call it fist time, its not updating the variable retornoServidor. I think its not giving time to execute http.postData.

```
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:109)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:109)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at br.com.c.Helper.AsyncTaskCodigo$1.<init>(AsyncTaskCodigo.java:53)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at br.com.asdf.Helper.AsyncTaskCodigo.doInBackground(AsyncTaskCodigo.java:53)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at br.com.sdfs.Helper.AsyncTaskCodigo.doInBackground(AsyncTaskCodigo.java:1)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-04 09:48:59.719: E/AndroidRuntime(18894):    ... 4 more
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894): Activity br.com.sdf.sdf.Activities.TelaCodigoActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40684d20 that was originally added here
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity br.com.sdf2.sdf.Activities.TelaCodigoActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40684d20 that was originally added here
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:261)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:170)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:113)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at br.com.sdf.Helper.AsyncTaskCodigo.onPreExecute(AsyncTaskCodigo.java:36)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at br.com.sdf.sdf.Activities.TelaCodigoActivity$1.onClick(TelaCodigoActivity.java:72)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
10-04 09:49:06.089: E/WindowManager(18894):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code

```
public class AsyncTaskCodigo extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

Context context;    
ProgressDialog progress;
String codigo;
long idUsuario; 
HttpRequest http = new HttpRequest();


public AsyncTaskCodigo(Context conetex, String codigo, long idUsuario){
    this.context = conetex;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
     progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Aguarde!", "Verificando o seu cófdigo...", true);     

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try{

        json.put("Codigo", codigo);
        json.put("Id_Usuario", idUsuario);

        http.postData(http.getUrltesteusuariocodigo(), json);
        publishProgress(1);

        if(http.temp.trim().equals("Yes")){
            TelaCodigoActivity.retornoServidor = "Yes";
        } else {
            TelaCodigoActivity.retornoServidor = "No";                                                  
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "ok";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    try {
        progress.dismiss();
        progress = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
     new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {                                        
          @Override
          public void onFinish() {

          }

          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

          }

      }.start();
}
```

}

Comment: It's a bad Idea to put it on doInBackground, just put it in onPostExecute

Comment: why you want make waiting doInBackGroundMethod ? Explain , so that we can give better solution

Comment: Im having to call 2 times this Asynctask. When I call it fist time, its not updating the variable retornoServidor. I think its not giving time to execute http.postData.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this counter code in onProgressUpdate() method. And call publishProgress() in doInbackground(). Your code will become like below

```
@Override
 protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try{

    json.put("Codigo", codigo);
    json.put("Id_Usuario", idUsuario);

    http.postData(http.getUrltesteusuariocodigo(), json);
    publishProgress();


    if(http.temp.toString().trim().equals("Yes")){
        TelaCodigoActivity.retornoServidor = "Yes";
    } else {
        TelaCodigoActivity.retornoServidor = "No";
    }


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return "ok";
}

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

try {
    progress.dismiss();
    progress = null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

   @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {                                        
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Its not calling the CountDownTimer. Its not passing 3 seconds.

Comment: what are u passing in publish progress? and also use this "AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>" at asynctask class creation. In this first parameter is your string passes to doInBacground. Second is your progress type which will pass and third paramter is your return type from doInbacground method. So arrange your thing accordingly.

Comment: Which values do I have to pass on publishProgress()?

Comment: pass any interger value

Comment: I passed 1. Its not calling onprogressUpdate()

Comment: Im having to call 2 times this Asynctask. When I call it fist time, its not updating the variable retornoServidor. I think its not giving time to execute http.postData

Comment: Cna you post complete asyntask class. It will clear your error.

Comment: Use publishprogress bfore http call.

Comment: I have to call it after htto call. I think its not giving time to execute http.postData. Im having to call this task to times to update the variable retornoServidor.